# wpf - контрол для отображения страниц

Tags: wpf, pagination, usercontrol, paging

хотелось бы найти пример реализации как можно проще и элегантнее с использованием mvvm управление страницами.
Т.е. задача - есть список и нужно вывести кнопки  для его постраничного представления
[<Назад] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [Далее>]

думаю сделать это через ItemsControl + ICollectionView, которая бы фильтровала отображаемые страницы ( 5 текущих ) но не совсем понятно насколько это кошерный способ и второй момент - как в ItemControl отображать выделенную текущую кнопку без лишних накруток кода.
Т.е ItemTemplate и код будет примерно следующий. Но что тут не нравится - то что PageItem при выполнении команды должен уведомлять PageCollection об изменении текущей позиции, хотелось бы чтобы работал IsSyncronizedCurrentItem, т.е. при клике на кнопку в CollectionView менялось состояние и CurrentItem переключался на текущую кнопку автоматом. Может есть какие-то решения более простые

```
 public class PageItem : BaseVM
 {
      ICommand SelectPageCommand {get;}
 }  

 public class PageCollection : BaseVM
 {
      ICollectionView Pages {get;}

      void CreatePages()
      {
          pages = new List<PageItem>();
          ...
          // create page items
          ...
          Pages = CollectionViewSource(pages)
          Pages.Filter+=(item)=>
          {
             // берем только 5 страниц от текущего элемента
          }
      }
 }

 <DataTemplate>
     <Button Command="{Binding SelectPageCommand} />
  </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: По существу ничем не отличается от стилизованного TabControl'а.